# Postgresql Bitmap Heap Scan slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-performance, trigram

My table looks like:

```sql
create table invoices
(
    id            serial not null,
    data          jsonb,
    modified      date,
    search_string text   not null
);
```

I need to search the table with `ILIKE` on `search_string`.
There may be many different search queries in the same request.

My query looks like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM invoices
WHERE (
    search_string ILIKE '%1%'
    OR search_string ILIKE '%2%'
    OR search_string ILIKE '%3%'
)
```

Explain for searching without index

```
Seq Scan on invoices  (cost=0.00..147139.51 rows=1004406 width=1006) (actual time=0.038..2341.489 rows=1004228 loops=1)
   Filter: ((search_string ~~* '%1%'::text) OR (search_string ~~* '%2%'::text) OR (search_string ~~* '%3%'::text))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 1943
 Planning Time: 4.682 ms
 Execution Time: 2427.400 ms
```

I tried to make it faster by creating GIN index:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
CREATE INDEX invoices_search_string_trigram_index ON invoices USING gin (search_string gin_trgm_ops);
```

Explain for searching with index

```
 Bitmap Heap Scan on invoices_invoice  (cost=414767.41..561902.40 rows=1004149 width=1006) (actual time=14878.331..17862.840 rows=1004228 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: ((search_string ~~* '%1%'::text) OR (search_string ~~* '%2%'::text) OR (search_string ~~* '%3%'::text))
  Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 1943
  Heap Blocks: exact=63341 lossy=66186
  ->  BitmapOr  (cost=414767.41..414767.41 rows=1006171 width=0) (actual time=14842.199..14842.199 rows=0 loops=1)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on trgm_idx_search_string  (cost=0.00..137979.36 rows=874048 width=0) (actual time=4520.466..4520.466 rows=546232 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (search_string ~~* '%1%'::text)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on trgm_idx_search_string  (cost=0.00..138208.03 rows=904538 width=0) (actual time=4357.453..4357.453 rows=546232 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (search_string ~~* '%2%'::text)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on trgm_idx_search_string  (cost=0.00..137826.91 rows=853721 width=0) (actual time=5964.276..5964.276 rows=546232 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (search_string ~~* '%3%'::text)
Planning Time: 1.198 ms
Execution Time: 17971.102 ms
```

Why are my index searches slower than seq scan?
 Is there any way to make this type of search faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem are probably the 66186 lossy blocks. Increase `work_mem` until you have only exact blocks.

Considering that you have a million result rows, I'd say that this query will never be very fast unless you reduce the number to result rows.

Answer (score 0):

How about `SIMILAR TO '[123]'` instead of 3 ILIKEs connected by OR?  That may be 3 times as fast.

Still, ILIKE and SIMILAR need to check every row.

When you add an INDEX, you tempt the Optimizer into thinking that the index will help.  But probably most of the rows have 1/2/3 in them, so the index becomes extra overhead.

Trigrams, as the name implies, work best when you have 3 consecutive characters to match.  But `%1%` is checking for only 1 character.  Hence most of the power of trigrams is wasted.